# Undesired Ctrl+V behaviour in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio

I encounter this fairly frequently:

I copy some text, then select the location at which I want to paste it, and hit <kbd>crtl</kbd> +<kbd>v</kbd>. Instead of copying the text, Texstudio loads the manual of a (seemingly) random package, then searches for the selected text in this manual (it loads the manual in the onboard pdf viewer).

This is very frustrating as some package manuals are large and it takes Texstudio some time to load them.

Does anybody have any idea why this is happening? I initially thought it was because I had made the pdf viewer the active window, but that can't be the case as I have just selected and copied some text, then selected the paste location.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Is this key listed as a shortcut in the edit menu?

Comment: Thanks :) Yes, as the hotkey for Paste